# How do I insert a value in one cell that appears in a column but stays permanent in that cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, finance, bloomberg, vba

I have a financial model that consists of current assets, liabilities etc. as the headers. I am looking to insert a stock ticker (AAPL US Equity as an example) into Cell A1, so that it appears in the column below. However, once the ticker appears in a cell (A2 for example), the next time I insert a ticker into A1, I would like it to appear in A3, and so on. The reason for this is because I am using formulas that automatically write in the statistics into the table, but first need the ticker on the beginning of the row.

```
                    TIME            PRICE       EPS         PE RATIO
AAPL US Equity      4:00:00PM       440.9       7.591       10.97977035
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a macro that detects the worksheet_change event!
Here's how you would code it.

```
Place this macro in the worksheet you want it to function!

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'check if the cell change is on A1
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" Then
        Dim lrow As Integer
        lrow = Me.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Me.Range("A" & lrow + 1) = Target
    End If
End Sub
```